# How to pass variable between screens in react native (see attached)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state, react-state-management

Please see snapshot attached: [Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmKqQ.jpg)

I'm trying to export this variable "email" from the 'List' screen, to the 'Account' screen without having to navigate to it as it is a bottomTabNavigator.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Here's the repo: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/federico-pi/tracks)

Comment: Use redux to share state between components. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux

Comment: Or use a parent component that keeps the state for both child components. Or you can even use `context` to share a state between components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some way you can handle that :

1. use `redux` in your project for access to your `states` in all of your project

for more info see [this](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

**this solution totally used in big project**

2. use `createContext` to save your some `props` and you can access that in other Screen for more info see [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

3.use `global` prop in project and you can `set` and `get` from that

for Example for set like that :

```
global.myProb=5;
```

and for get:

```
var m=global.myProb;
```

4. use `AsyncStorage` for save some data  . for more info see [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage)

Comment: Thanks for the 360-degree answer, I opted for the createContext approach and it did the trick!

The other 3 ways are new to me and are definitely worth looking into. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which sort of state management are you using.
In case of redux you can simply have a state that you communicate between the screens
or create a top level context with reducers hook to pass the data.